# Как редактировать файл в .txt через telebot?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, telegram

Как редактировать файл в .txt через telebot?
Имею бота в телеграм, который запускает разные файлы .py, где производится определенная вычислительная деятельность. Так вот, мне нужно редактировать один файл .txt к которым привязаны все .py.
приведу пример: допустим напишу я в телеграм "Смена курса"
а следующим сообщением присылаю курс "4.1112312" и он этот курс сохраняет в файл .txt

Или же я напишу в телеграм "смена курса 4.1112312" и он мне в .txt сохранит "4.1112312"

абсолютно не важно какой вариант будет( а может вы предложите мне какой то другой?)
самое главное, чтобы он мог редактировать файл (удалять старую запись и записывать присланную мной)

Comment: дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C+%D0%B2+%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
# тут принимаем сообщение от пользователя
message = 'смена курса 4.1112312'

# разбиваем строку по пробелам и берем последний элемент
message = message.split(" ")[-1]  

# Записываем данные в файл
with open("file.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(message)
```

Comment: Супер! Но мне нужно менять цифры периодически, а он записывает только "4.1112312"

Comment: Так вы принимайте сообщение от пользователя и записывайте в переменную 'message', и будет результат другой.

Comment: В этом и проблема, я не совсем понимаю как принимать сообщение с разным текстом, ведь я пишу фиксированное сообщение по которому бот принимает и записывает информацию, а тут сообщение постоянно меняется

Comment: @Михаил Как вариант сделайте обработчик команды, и ждите второго сообщения от пользователя. Например сначала пишем 'Смена курса', затем бот ждёт второе сообщение с самим курсом, например '3.581289' и берёт уже его. В таком случае вторая строчка с разделением не нужна.